# Dialog get value from another dialog which these two dialog are in the same page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, frameworks, dialog

In a page, I open a dialog using primefaces 5.0 dialog framework, called dialog A.
In the dialog A, for inputting data, I need to open another dialog using dialog framework, called dialog B. How could the A get the value from the B. Now I using the event "dialogReturn", but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Primefaces' userguide (Dialog Framework section):

`Nested dialogs are not supported`